# insert issues in an auto increment column

Tags: sql-server

How can I insert data into a column which has been defined as auto increment column using identity insert?please explain with an example.

Comment: but why do you want to insert data into an identity column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an "auto-increment" column - you really shouldn't be inserted specific values into that column yourself - after all, that's why it's an auto-increment column....

If you **must** do so after all - then you need to do:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT (your table name here) ON

INSERT INTO (your table name here) (IdentityCol, OtherCol1, .....)
VALUES( (new ID value), .......)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT (your table name here) OFF
```