# Insert values in a table which has an auto increment ID

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

How can I insert values in that kind of table? do I have to put the id with an empty value or...?

This is my code...

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO video(titulo, directorio, imagen, visitas, likes, usuario_id, fecha_subida, descripcion) VALUES ($titulo, $video_directorio, $imagen_directorio, 0, 0, $user, NOW(), $descripcion)";
```

Photo of my database **[LINK](https://gyazo.com/f41787921204a3e508cd0f76e3ce40fa)**

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: Did you test your code? What was the result?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL insert with auto increment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24121478/mysql-insert-with-auto-increment)

Comment: possible duplicate of [insert issues in an auto increment column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962664/insert-issues-in-an-auto-increment-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's an auto increment ID, don't specify that auto-increment-id-column and don't provide a value for it, that will be assigned automatically. So yes, just don't specify the ID column in your insert.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO video(titulo, directorio, imagen, visitas, likes, usuario_id, fecha_subida, descripcion) VALUES ($titulo, $video_directorio, $imagen_directorio, 0, 0, $user, NOW(), $descripcion)";

// proof that if we select that row, it has everything we inserted plus an id column
$sql2 = "SELECT * from video where titulo = '{$titulo}' and descripcion = '{$descripcion}'"; 
// ... query($sql2) #=> (1234, $titulo, $video_directorio, $imagen_directorio, 0, 0, $user, NOW(), $descripcion)
```